# Issue using Oracle date function with Spring's NamedParamenterJdbcTemplate

Tags: oracle, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm having an issue trying to get my SQL query which works fine in SQL Developer (Oracles free database tool) to also work using Spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate class.

My query is:

```
String sql = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( " +
                    " SELECT FE.USR_ID, MAX(FE.DATE_FIRST_SUB) AS SUB_DATE " +
                    " FROM FC, FE " +
                    " WHERE FC_STATUS = 'MEMBER' " +
                    " AND FC.FC_SPC_ID = :spcId " +
                    " AND FE.FE_USR_ID = FC.FC_USR_ID " +
                    " AND FE.DATE_FIRST_SUB IS NOT NULL " +
                    " GROUP BY FE_USR_ID " +
                 " ) " +
                 " WHERE SUB_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUN-2011', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01-JUL-2011', 'DD-MON-YYYY') ";
```

It has something to do with my dates, formatting perhaps? When I don't use the WHERE clause in the outer select it works, when it's included 0 is returned from the count - as I mentioned running the SQL directly returns expected results.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing obvious. Are you sure you are connecting to the same database/user. Without the outer WHERE, what is the MAX DATE_FIRST_SUB for that spcID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my, I was in fact looking at the wrong database!!